# How can I implement SfMap in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

> How can I implement SfMaps in my project which is based on MVVM structure? 1st I have to get my current location and show it on the map then I have to drag that marker point anywhere and set it as the current location

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/maps/getting-started

Comment: @Jason I need to implement it on as MVVM structure. adding dynamically markers and pin in project

Comment: What you posted is a list of requirements, not a question.  Please show us what you've tried and describe the specific problem you're having.  Please read [ask] for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Add SfMaps to your project from NuGet. In android no need for native configurations, but to launch the SfMaps in iOS, call the SfMapsRenderer.Init() in the FinishedLaunching overridden method of the AppDelegate class

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    …
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
    Syncfusion.SfMaps.XForms.iOS.SfMapsRenderer.Init();
    LoadApplication (new App ());
    …
}
```

Add the following namespace in your view file.

```
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfMaps.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfMaps.XForms"
```

And add the below code to initializing map in view

```
<maps:SfMaps >
  
</maps:SfMaps>
```

this is a very basic way to add SFMap in Xamarin. forms for more details and help
please visit this link: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/maps/getting-started?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xaml